# How do I extract a specific data from a Field in python to print it?

Tags: python, json, discord.py, bots

I'm using the discord.py API to build a bot to show me by different commands the results of some votes. For example, I have a question of *Do you like fruit?* And the options yes and no. I want to show by screen when you use the !votes command that the option 1 (yes) has 3 votes and the option 2 (no) has 1. The problem is that the variable that contains the number of votes is not an individual variable nor it gives it to me in JSON format, but in Field format (any). This returns postman when I make the request:

> "res" : "OrderedDict([('option', 'Yes'), ('number', 2), ('votes', 3)]),
> OrderedDict([('option', 'No'), ('number', 1), ('votes', 1)])"

From this, I only want the command to use the 'votes' part, but I don't know how to extract it from the string.

I extracted the other data from the other fields like this:

```
data = v.json()[1]
voter = data['voter']
```

since they are JSONField. But I don't know how to do it with the other form.

Could you please help me?

EDIT: I tried using this code I've seen in some questions here

```
 for line in res.split('OrderedDict'):
        vote = re.match(".*'votes',(\d+)", line)
        print(vote.group(1))
```

but it doesn't work either.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Why is the word `OrderedDict` in your JSON?

Comment: @eatmeimadanish that line is not in JSON format, but in Field format

Comment: Well since it is not pickled data, I doubt JSON will know to convert text data into an ordered dict.  My hunch is whatever first created that data was setup wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the discord API, but it looks like you've got a library returning an [`OrderedDict()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict). You should be able to treat this more or less equivalently to a normal Python dict, and retrieve values by key:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
choice = OrderedDict([('option', 'Yes'), ('number', 2), ('votes', 3)]) 
n_votes = choice['votes']
print(n_votes)
# 3
```

By the way, the example you've posted is broken somehow. The brackets are not balanced - could be a faulty copy-paste.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! but shouldn't I somehow access the res variable that contains that or somehow indicate that it is inside that variable? after the import

Comment: Also, the number of votes will be changing and I'm taking them from a gateway url so what I want is to receive that number, not have to enter it myself.

Comment: The code I've included is a minimal working example, but you'll have to adapt it to your use-case. You might need to do something like `my_response['res'][0]['votes']` if `my_response` is a variable containing your response dict.

It would help if you linked to the docs for the Discord library you're using, and included a [minimal reproducible example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)